# Executing drush in a bash script

Tags: drush

I'm under MacOSX and I'm struggling for hours trying to figure out how to make drush run from a bash script.
So let's say I create a named `build`, then I make it executable.
now I begin the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
drush cc drush
```

In the terminal if I make `./build`, it brings me result like : `Drush: command not found`
So how can I make it work?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/a/618442/31654

Comment: This is probably related to the path setting. Does `source build` still work if you open a new terminal?

Comment: the question is about executing the script, of course you have to be in the path where the script is logically. So if you want to execute it everywhere you can always create an alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!
If you call the script directly it doesn't work, better if ou source it like this: `source build`, then it works.
Anyway, I don't know if it's the better way to call this script.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/618442/31654

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `drush` command is within your `PATH` environmental variable.

If you're on macOS, place it in `/usr/local/bin` folder, then run this command to check that:

```
$ type -a drush
drush is /usr/local/bin/drush
```

And make sure that `/usr/local/bin` folder is part of your `PATH variable, e.g. by:

```
$ tr : "\n" <<<$PATH | grep usr.local.bin
/usr/local/bin
```